# How does a Generic Method Work?

Tags: c#, generics

I recently picked up this tutorial on MSDN that allow the user of my app to change and save settings. After some head scratching I think I understand all of it, except for one thing. Let's start with the most relevant part of the original code. Everything stands in a class called AppSettings. The property I'm using to test this is son1. What I understand is this:

At the end of the code, you got this:

```
 // Property to get and set son1 Key.
    public int son1
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<int>(son1KeyName, son1Default);
        }
        set
        {
            if (AddOrUpdateValue(son1KeyName, value))
            {
                Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you set the property, it's easy. It just calls this method:

```
public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;
 // If the key exists
        if (settings.Contains(Key))
        {
            // If the value has changed
            if (settings[Key] != value)
            {
                // Store the new value
                settings[Key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise create the key.
        else
        {
            settings.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        return valueChanged;
    }
```

I just have to do that and I'm done:

```
AppSettings param = new AppSettings();
        param.son1 = 1;
```

Now the syntax for the GET thing seems more strange to me . Process is the same, a method is used by a property. The get property is listed at the top of my post. As you can see, it calls this method:

```
public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
    {
        T value;

        // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
        if (settings.Contains(Key))
        {
            value = (T)settings[Key];
        }
        // Otherwise, use the default value.
        else
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

I'm disturbed by the "T", which is also written between < and >. If I could understand it, I should be able to set the property to the default value, wich I'll propably do at the beginning of my program. any tip is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your title with yout specific problem..

Comment: Read up on generic methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the syntax for [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

This is a complex subject, but it a few words: **it basically means your method can be used with multiple types. To simplify, you can replace your T by any type.** Instead of writing multiple functions:

```
public string GetValueOrDefault(string Key, string defaultValue)
public int GetValueOrDefault(string Key, int defaultValue)
```

you only write one:

```
T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
```

Answer (score 6):

> I'm disturbed by the "T", which is also written between < and >.

This indicates that it's a *generic method*.

Basically, you're not going to understand it without reading about [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/512aeb7t.aspx), which is *far* too big a topic to cover adequately in a Stack Overflow answer. Follow the link for the MSDN guide :)

The *very* brief version is that it means the method is parameterized by a *type* as well as by values. Generics can apply to types as well as methods, so a `List<string>` is a "list of strings" and a `List<int>` is a "list of integers". Generic methods are similar, but slightly harder to understand - here `GetValueOrDefault` could be described as "Returns a value of type `T`, based on the given string key - or returns the provided default value (also of type `T`) if the key doesn't exist in settings."

So `GetValueOrDefault<string>(key, "foo")` will return a `string` from the settings, defaulting to `"foo"`, and `GetValueOrDefault<int>(key, 10)` will return an `int` from the settings, defaulting to `10`.

That's just the 30 second walk through though - there's a **lot** more to learn :)

Comment: Your answer is just what I needed. Very well explained. I heard about generics, but never used them. I want to know c#, so I'll dig into it. I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

One prominent example of Generics, is the `List<T>`, which accepts any type and acts as a container for objects of that type.

```
List<int> intList; // a list of int
List<string> stringList; // a list of strings
```

Comment: Thank you very much. with all the help I quickly got from you gentlemen, I feel less intimidated. Too bad I can only check one answer as THE answer.